# Nodejs write test with ES6

Tags: node.js, express, testing, ecmascript-6

I like coding with ES6 syntax. So my nodejs backend project i create with this structure :
[image]

In **src** folder, i code using ES6 syntax, then i use gulp-babel to transpile into nodejs readable code in **dist** folder. But I find that i cannot write the unit test to coverage the code because the unit test must use the readable code in dist folder.

So I need some suggestions that help me using the ES6 syntax and write unit test to coverage the code in src folder. Thank you.

Comment: You could use `babel-node` to run your tests